# Access Consumer from View to push api-received data to User via WebSocket (Django-Channelsv2.2 & DRF)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, celery, django-channels

I found myself struggling to find a way to push data to Consumer (Django Channels v.2.2) from View (APIView Django-rest-framework) or distributed task (Celery/RabbitMQ directly)

I'd really appreciate any code sample that would allow me to access the consumer from View as the trigger itself is the input device, not a web, so I can make API call from it, so I need the connector.

Django Channels v.2.2, DjangoChannelsRestFramework, mostly all the cases described here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community.html as well as correlating questions @stackoverflow

consumers.py

```
class BasicConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
        # await self.send({
        #     "type": "websocket.send",
        #     "text": "Hello world"
        # })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print('receive', event)
        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg = loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            print(msg)
            user = self.scope['user']

            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.username
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username
            }
            await self.send({
                "type": "websocket.send",
                "text": json.dumps(myResponse)
            })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('disconnect', event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]
```

views.py

```
class BasicView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = BasicViewSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           triggerConsumer(serializer.validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to define a channel name and send data to it.

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("channel_name", {...})
```

you can see the full document here [doc](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#synchronous-functions)

Comment: Thank you, Omid. Have you done this before? Can I ask you to sketch the sample code that would send the seralizers's validated data from the example to one of the BasicConsumer methods?

Comment: @Aleks_Saint you need to add a separate consumer method to handle the serializer data. The basic consumer methods already have specific usages so you shouldn't use them for that. Again, check the docs page he linked

Comment: Give a more detailed answer.